How to find where Flask decided to host my CSS file
I'm having an issue where when I test my flask app locally, the app has no problem finding the static folder. But when I deploy my app in a container and host it in a kubernetes cluster, the app seems to be looking in the wrong place for the css file, and I can't find where it should be looking.
My current file structure:
App/
--static/
----main.css
----favicon.ico
--templates/
----index.html
--app.py
--page.py

in my html template file I reference the css file with
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='main.css') }}"></link>

for brevity, my app.py file is:
import os
from flask import Blueprint, Flask
from App import page

ROOT_PATH = os.environ['ROOT']
PORT      = os.environ['PORT']

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = ROOT_PATH

bp = Blueprint( 'root_path', __name__ )
bp.register_blueprint( page.my_page )
app.register_blueprint( bp, url_prefix=ROOT_PATH )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        '0.0.0.0',
        PORT
    )

And my page file as well.
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

my_page = Blueprint( 'my_page', __name__ )

@my_page.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    # PAGE LOGIC
    return render_template( 'index.html' )

When I run locally, the page runs on a url like http://0.0.0.0:12345/page_route/, here the CSS loads correctly. Grabbing its url, it seems flask is serving it at http://0.0.0.0:12345/static/main.css. This all works just fine
When I run on the cluster, the page runs on a url like https://mycluster:54321/app_root/page_route, where the cluster has to host the app in a namespace. This page works correctly and I have set the root prefixes in my app to adjust the url accordingly. However the CSS does not get loaded, and when I look at the console it says its looking for the CSS down https://mycluster:54321/static/main.css, which doesn't exist because it would be outside the namespace. I thought this meant I wasn't setting some prefix somewhere, but when I looked down other paths I couldn't find the CSS hosted anywhere.
My question is a general one about how this should work, or if there is some config i'm forgetting to set in my app.py file. Where should the static file be, and is it possible for find where Flask might be trying to host it? I suspect this has something to do with my needing to set these root prefixes and flask isn't seeing it somewhere
all variables have been generalized for privacy

I'm not sure if it helps, but when instantiating Flask you can specify static_url_path to specify the path prefix that will be added to the URL to serve files from the static folder. The default value is static. Perhaps assigning ROOT_PATH + '/static' might work. However, it seems to me that some sort of proxy configuration outside of Flask makes more sense.

Did you try https://mycluster:54321/app_root/static/main.css by chance?

@Detlef Yes I found this just a couple minutes ago and I'm testing it now, it seems to do what I wanted locally so i'm thinking this is it.

@JonSG i did try that path and it also did not exist. I'm thinking it was trying to host on the cluster url, which its not allowed to do, so this static_url_path should be able to give it a url its allowed to host on.

Your app's hyperlink references to app content should be relative e.g. /static/main.css. Following this approach, the behavior should work whether you run the app locally or containerize it and run it anywhere (including Kubernetes). Kubernetes Namespaces do not affect this behavior. The only behavioral change from Kubernetes Namespaces would be that the in-cluster service URL would change (per Namespace) but relative references would always work. You don't include your containerfile (Dockerfile).

The answer here as pointed out by @Detlef in the comments is to set the static_url_path parameter upon instantiating Flask.
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path=f"{ROOT}/static")

What I didn't understand was that Flask will automatically attempt to serve static files to /static/<path:filename> and this will happen at instantiation. So anything I did that effects url prefixes would not be picked up by the static route unless I followed a couple steps to override it as laid out in this answer.
I also missunderstood what was happening with my kubernetes namespace, as pointed out by @DazWilkin, what I called my namespace was actually my istio-virtual-service setting a prefix to my apps normal uri, this prefix just happens to contain my namespace name as well.
Ultimately this answer shows a way to serve static files to your app when the uri gets changed from some other factor of your environment.
